Export charts from R in Word with high quality
I typically use R to create graphs with ggplot2, and they look fantastic when exported to PDF documents.
However, I encounter an issue when trying to incorporate these graphs into Word documents.
I usually export in PDF and resort to using the Snipping Tool and pasting them into Word, but this drastically reduces the quality.
Surprisingly, the quality is even worse than when I create graphs in Excel and transfer them to Word. Below you can see one one example
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)

wdata = data.frame(
  sex = factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each=200)),
  weight = c(rnorm(200, 55), rnorm(200, 58)))

a <- ggplot(wdata, aes(x = weight))

a + geom_area(stat = "bin",
              color= "black", fill="#00AFBB")


Can someone help me with a method to transfer them to Word without losing their quality?

I extract to PDF and after that with Snipping Tool , pasting into Word

ggsave(filename, width=, height=, res=). Then in Word, Insert...Pictures....

Thank you ! Some proposal about width= and height= , for chart  which need to take lets say half page of A4 format ?

The default units are inches, so maybe 4?

My default method for this is to use an rmarkdown or quarto document and set the DPI in that. It keeps the resolution in the output document:
---
title: "Test graphs"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,
                      dpi = 900)
```

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)

wdata = data.frame(
  sex = factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each=200)),
  weight = c(rnorm(200, 55), rnorm(200, 58)))

a <- ggplot(wdata, aes(x = weight))

a + geom_area(stat = "bin",
              color= "black", fill="#00AFBB")
```


Microsoft tends to cause issues with interpolation of units. so MS Edge reports PDF pages as metric units 133% larger than life. Basically they interchange at 96/72 !
As others mention there are several advanced settings such as do not compress!

With insert to Word there is a different issue and that is down sampling so here the source is 57% and input re-sampled will often generate a poor result. So manual change scale to close integer ratio can help 1/2 = 50% see below 3rd image click to see at 100% for pdf 50% scaled quality.



However, whatever you do, Word is always down sampling the images (see 50% import below) so best to set the desired size before import.

